# Delete 0's from cell upon entry

Tags: vba, excel

I want a macro so that when you enter a `0` into a particular cell/range of cells that it clears the cell.

I wrote a simple macro like this

```
Sub RemoveZeros()
'to remove 0 values that may be a result of a formula or direct entry.

    For Each cell In Range("A1:D20")
        If cell.Value = "0" Then cell.Clear
    Next

End Sub
```

However, I have to run this after I have entered my values for it to clear. I would like the cell to clear if a `0` is entered. How do I do this?

Comment: Open the `ThisWorkbook` module create a sub called `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` and enter your code in there.  The code will fire when you change a cell value on any sheet.

Comment: Also - wouldn't it be just as easy to select a cell and hit `Delete` if the end result is an empty cell?  No VBA needed.

Comment: And use the `Target` variable, example: `If Target Like "*0*" Then Target.Clear` or `If Target = 0 Then Target.Clear`

Comment: Thanks guys, I have it working now. However what about for a merged cell. I have tried using target.unmerge.clearcontents but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
      If Target.Value = 0 Then Target.ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Yep, that'll do it. It will work on any cell on that sheet and not just in the range A1:D20.  If you want to limit the range it works on wrap your three lines of code in an `IF...END IF` statement:  `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:D20")) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: Thanks man. In this particular instance there is one cell I want to change to zero. However this cell is merged. How do I go around that?

Comment: You could use `Target.MergeArea.ClearContents`.  This will work even if it's an unmerged single cell.  If it's a single cell you could also use `If Target.Address = "$E$10" Then` rather than the whole `Intersect` thing.

Comment: perfect that worked! I was doing target.unmerge.clearcontents but i now see why that is wrong